# Simple auth page with html redirection

Tags: html, authentication

I'm trying to build a very simple auth page that allows me to control a header. I'm very much a noob when it comes to HTML and have been reading tons of examples. I currently have an nginx container with a custom HTML landing page that uses a simple HTML login form. The landing page has 2 frames. One frame is the header with the page controls (the changes the lower frame) and I'm using a login example from w3 schools. What I'm trying to figure out is how can I make the landing page be the login page, and then have a simple auth system that redirects to the login landing page to the page with the iframes. I've been looking at a ton of tutorials but I can't seem to figure this out. Can someone direct me to an article that might help guide me through this process?

Comment: Are you ok to use Basic Authorization? It seems that it would be the easiest way to achieve authorization without any additional actions

Comment: Yea, Its not a crazy secure service and I'm not looking to even use https (i dont have any ssl certs and I'm using a noip dns). I put the login page in place to make people think there is active security but it would be nice if the login page did something other than act as a deterrent.